# How to get Details in Captured image in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to know how to get image details from captured image. like latitude and longitude and title. My programme capture image I want to get its details to programme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) you can get attributes of the captured image provided your camera was configured to write them

Answer (score 4):

To get image details use:

```
final ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageUri.getPath());
final int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
final String datestamp = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP);
final String gpsLatitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
final String gpsLatitudeRef = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
...
```